# Kubernetes expose a service does not assign the external ip

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

I have an internal service that is created via the first cmd. Then i run kubectl expose on that service that is created.

```
kubectl -n XXX create -f service.yml
kubectl -n XXX get svc
NAME                                 TYPE        CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)                                                                            AGE
foo                           ClusterIP   10.152.183.41    <none>        8089/TCP


kubectl -n XXX expose service foo --type=NodePort --name=foo-ext
kubectl -n XXX get svc
NAME                                 TYPE        CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)                                                                            AGE
foo                           ClusterIP   10.152.183.41    <none>        8089/TCP                                                                           29m
foo-ext                   NodePort    10.152.183.177   <none>        8089:30406/TCP
```

Where the external ip is  I would have figured kubectl expose would have assigned an external ip to the external service, is there an additional flag i need to pass?

Answer (score 2):

According to the [Kubernetes docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#type-nodeport):

> If you set the type field to NodePort, the Kubernetes master will allocate a port from a range specified by --service-node-port-range flag (default: 30000-32767), and each Node will proxy that port (the same port number on every Node) into your Service.

So, Kubernetes will ensure that the same port number is exposed on all nodes that are hosting this service. The external IP, in this case, is the IP address of the node.

Whereas Kubernetes says this about [External IPs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#external-ips):

> If there are external IPs that route to one or more cluster nodes, Kubernetes services can be exposed on those externalIPs. Traffic that ingresses into the cluster with the external IP (as destination IP), on the service port, will be routed to one of the service endpoints. **`externalIPs`** are not managed by Kubernetes and are the responsibility of the cluster administrator.

The downside to a `NodePort` type of service is that, by itself, it's not a scalable approach and lacks service discoverability.

If you want to expose a service through a single IP address to consumers outside of your Kubernetes cluster, you may want to look into [`LoadBalancer`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#type-loadbalancer) type of service if have a public cloud or hybrid cloud Kubernetes deployment, or you may want to look into [`Ingress`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/) if you have an on-premises Kubernetes deployment.

Comment: Note, that in case of NodePort type of service, if you run "kubectl get service" "EXTERNAL-IP" column for that service will be empty. But you can access that service using IP address of any node in the cluster and random(but the same for all nodes) or port specified in service spec.ports.port.nodePort option.

Comment: Just want to add that `Ingress` makes sense in public cloud Kubernetes deployments as well in contrast to `LoadBalancer` service type. LoadBalancer service type is generally not used if you have to expose multiple services outside the cluster due to cost.

Answer (score 0):

`LoadBalacer` type service "assigns" an external IP, but it is cloud provider specific, so it won't work. Unless you have a load balancer pointing to the cluster (with an external IP, of course).

From the other services, your only option would be `NodePort` type service, which would map your pod port to a port on the node, so it will be accessible from outside world. The ugly part is that it is going to be on a port like 30021 (between 30000-32767).